# i need to add sub menu to my css menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

i want my submenu to slide to right in horizontal, i tried some other css menu, but it is creating problem in my web page.
this is my html page for the menu

```
<li class="widget">
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" title="Category 1">All </a></li>
        <li><a href="search.php?category=Groceries" title="Category 1">Groceries</a></li>
        <li><a href="search.php?category=Personal_care" title="Category 2">Personal Care</a></li>
        <li><a href="search.php?category=Dining" title="Category 5">Dining</a></li>
        <li><a href="search.php?category=entertainment" title="Category 7">Entertainment</a></li>
        <li><a href="search.php?category=travel" title="Category 6">Travel </a></li>
        <li><a href="search.php?category=Books_Magazine" title="Category 3">Books &amp; Magazine</a></li> 
        <li><a href="search.php?category=clothing" title="Category 4">Clothing</a></li>
        <li><a href="search.php?category=Sport_Fitness" title="Category 9">Sport &amp; Fitness</a></li>
        <li><a href="search.php?category=other" title="Category 11">Other</a></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and this is my css for the menu, how can i add css to create a drowp down sub menu in right

```css
.widget { padding-bottom: 16px; }
.widget h2 {
    height: 37px;
    line-height: 37px;
    background: url('images/widget-title.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    font-family: 'Museo500', arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 9px 5px 22px;
}
.widget li a {
    background: #6692C6;
    line-height: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    padding-left: 23px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    display: block;
}
.widget li.last a { border: none; }
.widget li a:hover {
    color: #333333;
    background: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by sliding to the right. Can you please elaborate. Also see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gbutv/2/, is this what you mean ?

Comment: in my css there is no css written to drop down sub menu, i mean if the user clicks on the clothing menu or on mouse over, i want the drop down submenu as men's clothing, women's clothing, thats what i mean thank you

Comment: OK! I completely misunderstood your question then. You need to have a little bit of javascript for that as well

Comment: Have you tried jquery menu plugin http://jqueryui.com/menu/

Comment: the reason why am not using jquery because, my other js doest not work if i place a new js source link,
so im trying solve out with css

Answer (score 0):

see how this works

**HTML**

```
<li class="widget">
<h2>Categories</h2>
<div class='subMenu'>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php" title="Category 1">All </a></li>
    <li><a href="search.php?category=Groceries" title="Category 1">Groceries</a></li>
    <li><a href="search.php?category=Personal_care" title="Category 2">Personal Care</a</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.subMenu{
display:none;
}
.widget:hover .subMenu{
 display:block;
}
```

**fiddle**

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Venugopal/gbutv/3/)